# What if a static member is not initialized and the member type is class itself?

Tags: c++

A class is defined like this:

```
class Singleton {
public:
    static Singleton instance_;

private:
    Singleton() {
        cout << "constructor\n";
    }
};
```

In a function:

```
Singleton instance = Singleton::instance_;
```

Code can be compiled and no error was thrown. If I use it like this:

```
Singleton &instance = Singleton::instance_;
```

A link error was thrown. I wonder why the first case can be compiled correctly? And I know the constructor function was not called. What's the object state of instance in the first case? Does the first case make any sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both forms are an error in your code, but in both cases compilers/linkers are allowed to silently ignore the error, they're not required to detect it.

`Singleton instance = Singleton::instance_;` uses the implicitly generated copy constructor. It copies all 0 non-static data members from `Singleton::instance_`, and is therefore likely to be optimised away entirely. Therefore, the fact that you're using `Singleton::instance_` without a definition is likely to go unnoticed.

`Singleton &instance = Singleton::instance_;` binds to `Singleton::instance_` and requires its address to be known. Therefore, it is more likely to result in an error if `Singleton::instance_` is not defined.

The way you can provide a definition of `Singleton::instance_` is

```
Singleton Singleton::instance_;
```

at file scope.

Comment: Hit the point! If I define my copy constructor rather than use a default one, the code can't be compiled. It seems the compiler did ignore the error after the optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Static members are only *declared* when the class is defined. They must be defined outside of the class definition. In your case, you should write:

class Singleton {

```
public:
    static Singleton instance_; // declare the static member

private:
    Singleton() {
        cout << "constructor\n";
    }
};

Singleton Singleton::instance_; // defines the static member
```

This is mainly used when you need non trivial construction, but if you forget to define the static member, it simple does not exists and you get either a link error or undefined behaviour at run time.

Comment: Thanks. I just wonder why the first case can be compiled. I thought it couldn't.